# Buoyancy frequency

Tags: atmosphere, temperature, atmospheric-circulation

The buoyancy frequency, $N$ is defined as $N^2=\frac{gd\theta}{\theta dz}$, where $\theta$ is the potential temperature (I see it as a measure of the deviation from the adiabatic nature), 
$z$ is the vertical co-ordinate and 
$g$ is the acceleration due to gravity and sometimes $\theta$ is replaced with potential density. My question is why not use $T(z)$ (usual temperature) instead of $\theta(z)$ to define $N$?

Comment: If you start from the derivation of the frequency (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brunt%E2%80%93V%C3%A4is%C3%A4l%C3%A4_frequency#Derivation_for_a_general_fluid), you see that in reality it is based on density. In the atmosphere, potential temperature has the same properties with regards to buoyancy as density and they can be substituted.

Comment: Because $\theta(z) = const.$ for an isentropc i.e. adiabatic atmosphere, whereas  $T(z) \neq const.$.

Answer (score 3):

You can, but the form changes. it is

$N^2=\frac{g}{T}(\frac{dT}{dz} + Γ)$

where $Γ$ is the dry adiabatic lapse rate, given by $g/c_p$

where $c_p$ is the specific heat of air at constant pressure.